# how to add Username Password authentication to secure web socket client and how to test it

Tags: java, android, sockets, websocket

I am newbie and been working around secure web socket in **java**. i was able to do that and tested it with **echo server(wss://)**. so now to make it more secure i want to use **Username password authentication**.What all possible way are there to authenticate a user before secure websocket start their work?
Mainly my aim is to create an android library which can be used to send and receive data over secure websocket with authentication.

And

How can i test the http authentication? is there any mock server, like there is echo server to test websocket.

Comment: i went through [This](http://www.tomitribe.com/blog/2015/05/websocket-and-lock-it/) but it is for authenticating over HTTP. i am using wss for which HTTPS will be requied. please correct me if am wrong

Comment: Authenticating the connection is different then securing the connection. HTTPS and WebSocket use SSL for security, so the connection is secure the moment it is established, before any protocol data (HTTP, WebSocket) is exchanged. WebSocket starts out with an ordinary HTTP request to upgrade the connection to 2-way WebSocket, so you can use HTTP authentication (separate from SSL security) before allowing the upgrade to proceed.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau. so what i understood is that even "wss" will start out with "http" not with "https". so I can use "http authentication" here instead of "https authentication". correct me if i misunderstood the concept.
How can test it? i have modified title also regarding this.

Comment: WS is plain WebSocket and starts life as plain HTTP. WSS is WebSocket over SSL/TLS, so it starts life as HTTPS, not HTTP. There is no such thing as HTTPS Authentication, only HTTP Authentication. HTTPS is still HTTP, just over SSL/TLS. Just as WSS is WS, just over SSL/TLS.

Comment: ok, got it. thanks @RemyLebeau.

Comment: For the buddies who faces similar issue.
To test authentication what i did is ==>
Created http server using http server using c#.
set AuthenticationSchemes as AuthenticationSchemes.Basic.
From client code set authentication same as that of server i.e basic authehtication.
Supply any username and password.Authentication will pass.